# How to reload the Firewalld service using Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have added some rules to firewalld on CentOS via Ansible. But I need to reload the firewalld daemon for the service to work properly and permanently. Is there a way to do this in Ansible?

Here is my Ansible code:

```
- name: Add port to firewalld
  firewalld:
    port: "{{ item }}"
    permanent: yes
    state: enabled
  when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' or ansible_distribution == 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux'
  loop:
    - 8080/tcp
    - 8000/tcp
    - 8090/tcp
    - 8040/tcp
```

Comment: if it's managed by systemd or some other init service,shouldn't invoking a `service` task satisfy this? Can you tell us whether the code you're using actually works or if not how it fails?

Comment: Actually, I need to reload firewalld after this task. 
I think one way is to use the service module in the next step, but is there any way to do this with the firewalld module itself?

Comment: You probably want to trigger a handler for this then (notify: <handler name>)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/firewalld_module.html) the firewalld module can only be used to add / remove / update rules from the firewalld ruleset. To reload the service use the `service` module like this (as per [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html)):

```
- name: Always reload firewalld
  ansible.builtin.service:
    name: firewalld
    state: reloaded
```